# Forgot Apple ID no email, no phone #

Tags: iphone, apple-id, password

I forgot my Apple ID password, don't have access to the email anymore and I changed my number. The problem is it's not giving me the security questions options

Comment: Call Apple support, be prepared to provide proof of (legal) ownership

Comment: While it doesn't hurt to try, Apple Support usually cannot help except to point you to the right resources for resetting your password. This process is intentionally walled off from the people who run support to ensure social engineering is minimized

Answer (score 1):

The article "[If you forgot your Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487)"outlines the **only** way to reset your password:

Summary of the key points:

- If you have a device that's still signed into your Apple ID, you can reset the password from that device's settings. You go to the Settings / System Preferences app and open your **Apple ID** > **Password & Security page**. There, you can **Change Password**.
- If you do not, you must use Apple's "[Recover Your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com)".

---

The article "[Change your Apple ID security questions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201363)" outlines how security questions work:

Summary of the key points:

- You no longer have security questions if you enabled two-factor authentication. You must use the account recovery flow at "[Recover Your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com)" (more on that below).

---

Lastly, as I mentioned, if you have enabled two-factor authentication you will not have security questions. Thus, you must follow the flow at "[Recover Your Apple ID](https://iforgot.apple.com)". Information on that process is found in the article "[How to use account recovery when you can’t reset your Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921)".

Account recovery is done by email, phone, and sometimes by credit card. Follow the prompts given and you may be able to recover your account.